# Google Places for iOS version 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places-api

Today Google released version 3 of its Places API for iOS. Upgrading my project and using the new `findPlaceLikelihoodsFromCurrentLocationWithPlaceFields`method I get the following error:

> "Pick Place error The operation couldn’t be completed. An internal
>   error occurred in the Places API library...."

Any ideas?

Here is my complete Objective C code:

```
GMSPlaceField fields = GMSPlaceFieldName;
GMSPlacesClient *placesClient;
placesClient = [GMSPlacesClient sharedClient];

[placesClient findPlaceLikelihoodsFromCurrentLocationWithPlaceFields:fields callback:^(NSArray* likelihoods, NSError* error){

    if(error != nil)
    {
        //##
        NSLog(@"Pick Place error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }

    for(GMSPlaceLikelihood *likelihood in likelihoods)
    {
        //##
        NSLog(@"likelihood.place : %@",likelihood.place.name);
    }
}];
```

Comment: Could your print error instead of the localized Description, and give the full error message loggued then?

Comment: I get 'This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure this API is activated in the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/places_backend?project=_'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Google changed things without being terribly obvious.

In my case, I used to have the "Places SDK for iOS" restriction added on the API key, but the new stuff requires the "**Places API**" restriction.

Comment: This is the correct answer. In your Google Cloud Platform console page, select the project you are working on. Then from the dropdown menu on the very top left, select "APIs and Services" and then "Library". Search for "places" and select the "Places API" button. And then Enable it. Done. Thanks @yoitsro!